# Why is Powershell able to change registry values regardless of registry permissions?

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, windows-registry, powershell, regedit

Using Windows 8.1 Enterprise. Through Regedit I removed permissions from Administrators and even System for the key `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

I was under the assumption that that would prevent changes to any of these keys. Still though, through PowerShell, I was still able to change the value for `ProxyEnable` using the following command:

`set-itemproperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ProxyEnable -value 1`

Does PowerShell run as some super user or something without regard to permissions set up in Regedit?

Comment: Just a silly question, did you remove the permissions using the same account that you're attempting to change them from? It's just that HKCU is a per-user key, so if you're using a different account it would explain the problem.

Comment: Check the permissions via PowerShell to see if they look like what you are expecting: `get-acl "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | format-list`

Comment: Powershell always runs with

Comment: Not a silly question at all. I think I apparently had a misunderstanding of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. I have an admin user and a non-admin account. I noticed my Internet Settings are messed up on the admin account since I completely removed permissions to Internet Settings keys. The non-admin account is fine though. I apparently was not actually editing the non-admin account I was trying to affect. I think that was the issue. Now I need to be careful when I actually apply the permissions to the non-admin registry. I will post back to here if I still see any issues.